# I'm facing issue on cluttering the screen of every page of layout using Vuetify UI component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm facing the issue of clutter the screen layout on reload the every page. Currently i'm using the Vuetify version - '1.5.14', Nuxt version - '2.7.1'. I removed the app.styl from nuxt.config.js because of css code repeat in every page and added the directly in plugin vuetify.js as "import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl';". I don't know what is exactly issue Please help someone about this issue.

import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl';

added directly in vuetify.js

I'm expecting don't clutter the screen after refresh the page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byBqj.png)